# Alguma maneira de permitir o carregamento de script inserido pelo dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: javascript, react

```js
function createMarkup(str) {
    return { __html: str };
  }

  function GraphicLarge({ HTMLData }) {
    return (
      <div className="graphic graphic--lg">
        { isFetching ? <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(HTMLData)} /> : <Loading /> }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```html
<!-- 
  ./statics/html/grafico1.html
  
  # HTML que preciso inserir 
  # Eu busco esse HTML com uma requisição.
  
-->

<link href="https:/example.br/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="grafico">
  <img src="https:/example.br/img/1.svg" alt="Imagem" />
  <h1>Conteudo do gráfico</h1>
</div><!-- /#grafico -->

<script src="https:/example.br/js/libs/graph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https:/example.br/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Estou fazendo uma tarefa que busca um arquivo **.html**, por exemplo: Um pedaço de um gráfico. 
O lance é que os arquivos **JS** desse html não são executados (nem mesmo carregados) quando o html é inserido no DOM pela função **dangerouslySetInnerHTML** .
Os outros estáticos (CSS, Imagens e fontes) são carregados sem nenhum problema.

Comment: O `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` é para evitar o tipo de código que estás a tentar usar. Deves fazer isso de outra maneira. Esses arquivos JS vêm de onde? Estás a usar webpack?

Comment: Então, é essa outra maneira que preciso aprender. Uso o webpack sim.
Vou tentar colocar um exemplo na descrição. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Parece que uma alternativa é usar esse cara: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/createContextualFragment